# Check if there is an error in update/insert | MongoDB Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

**I want to check if an `insert` fails** (due to unique=True index in the collection). If there is an error do something. Bellow is an example of my code.

```
DBCollection user...;
BasicDBObject Doc = new BasicDBObject(... );

String user_exists = user.insert(Doc).getError(); //insert the doc get error if any
if(user_exists!=null){ //any errors?
    user.update(new BasicDBObject(...)); // error exists so do smthng
}
```

The above as it is does not work. I believe that the `String user_exists` is always null. How can I make the above work?

---

I have seen similar SO questions and mention the [WriteConcern](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html) which can be passed in the `insert()`. E.g.

```
coll.insert(dbObj, WriteConcern.SAFE);
```

sources: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20022811/1447885)
or 
[Mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-concurrency/)

However I do not know which one field should I pass (SAFE, ACKNOWLEDGED, UNACKNOWLEDGED etc..) in order to get the error. Maybe I'm pointed in the wrong direction.

I do not wish to raise an exception just to check if there is an error returned by the `insert` operation.

Comment: Could you rephrase "However I do not know which one field should I pass or handle the rest." as it makes little sense

Comment: @Martin Updated. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Yes, the various WriteConcern fields are desribed in http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html#field_summary

Comment: The com.mongodb.MongoException.DuplicateKey is unavoidable if the dbObj you are writing violates some unique key constraint.  That is just now the Mongo driver works.  We are always WriteConcern.SAFE here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED` (which I think is also `SAFE`) you don't need to pollute your code with error checking.

For `ACKNOWLEDGED`, the driver will automatically issue a `getLastError` command automatically and raise an exception if anything got wrong, for example duplicate index violation.

Starting from v2.10 of the Java Driver, the default Write Concern is `ACKNOWLEDGED`

**EDIT**

> I do not wish to raise an exception just to check if there is an error returned by the insert operation.

You shouldn't do this, but in any case:

The `insert` method indeed returns `WriteResult`. If it's `getError()` is `null`, everything is OK, otherwise it returns something such as `E11000 duplicate key error index:...`. For this to work, you will have to use `WriteConcern.UNACKNOWLEDGED`

Comment: Sweet but how can I run the `.update()`? I still want to run it if something goes wrong :)

Comment: Does anyone know if this is documented on the MongoDB pages somewhere? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Find more info on [write concerns here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/) and the documentation on save can be found at http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html ;  note that a MongoExcption is thrown, and it extends from RuntimeException